# Real Analysis Supremum Proof Help

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $s\in \mathbb{R}$ have the property that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $s+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for $A$ and $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $A$. Prove that $s = \sup A$.

I honestly have no idea where to even start here, it feels like a super simple problem but I just don't know where to start

Comment: Hint: $s+1/n$ being an upper bound will prove $s$ is also an upper bound. $s-1/n$ not being an upper bound will prove $s$ is the least such one.

Comment: thank you, this helps a lot @podiki

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $s$ is not the supremum of $A$. Suppose $\sup A < s$. There exists $n\in N$ such that $s - 1/n > \sup A$. Therefore, $\sup A \geq s$.
Suppose $\sup A > s$. As there exists $n\in N$ such that $s+1/n < \sup A$, and $s+1/n$ is an upper bound $\sup A \leq s$. So $\sup A = s$